# Can multiple colors be used on items in a single JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, paintcomponent

I am learning to use swing to create user interfaces. Currently, I have this JFrame and I need to place a shape inside it and provide methods to move the shape. I call the shape object Robot.

I want to draw something more creative than just a single red square. I have figured out how to add multiple shapes, but they are still all the same color. How can I use more than one color on this single JFrame?

```
public class SwingBot 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setTitle("SwingBot");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Robot r = new Robot();

    frame.add(r);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean repeat = true;
    System.out.println();
    while (repeat)
    {
        String str = in.next();
        String direc = str.toLowerCase();
        if (direc.equals("right"))
        {
            r.moveBot(10,0);
        }
        else if (direc.equals("left"))
        {
            r.moveBot(-10,0);
        }
        else if (direc.equals("up"))
        {
            r.moveBot(0,-10);
        }
        else if (direc.equals("down"))
        {
            r.moveBot(0,10);
        }
        else if (direc.equals("exit"))
        {
            repeat = false;
        }
    }

}


public static class Robot extends JComponent
{
    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(Color.RED);

        g2.fill(rect);
    }

    public void moveBot(int x, int y)
    {
        rect.translate(x,y);

        repaint();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You just need to call `setColor` with a different color before painting each shape.

Comment: If I add another setColor to the paintComponent method, all of the shapes within that object are set to the last color in the sequence regardless of what ever else is listed.

Comment: I'd suggest posting the code that fails, so that people can see what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is call the `setColor` method with a new `Color` of your `Graphics` object each time you paint a new component.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fillRect(...);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fillOval(...)
}
```

Comment: Okay. I was doing this very incorrectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can call:

```
g.setColor(your color here);
```

before you draw a shape with another color.

**Example**:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);   //Fill a Red Rectangle

    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillOval(20, 20, 50, 50);   //Fill a Yellow Circle
}
```

You probably also want to call `super.paintComponent(g)` in your paintComponent() method to prevent visual artifacts.

Comment: **Remarks:** Since you are downcasting Graphics to Graphics2D, the same applies. May still call `g2.setColor(your color)`;

Answer (score 1):

You could provide your Robot class with a Color attribute that you can change before calling moveBot.

Something like:

```
public static class Robot extends JComponent{
    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10);
    private Color col = Color.RED;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(col);
        g2.fill(rect);
    }

    public void setColor(Color c){
       col = c;
    }

    public void moveBot(int x, int y)
    {
        rect.translate(x,y);

        repaint();
    }
}
```